# OwlCarousel2 interval not working when swipe manfully

Tags: owl-carousel

My OwlCarousel2 interval works when it's sliding automatically but if it's swiped manually it slides faster than interval timing any solution.

here is my code

```
var slidercode;

// Slider
var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    rtl: false,
    items:1,
    nav:false,
    autoplay:true,
    dots: true,
});
setDelay();


owl.on('dragged.owl.carousel', function () {
    slidercode = '1';
    setDelay();
});

owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel translated.owl.carousel', function () {
    if(slidercode!=1){
        slidercode = '2';
        setDelay();
    }
});
function setDelay(){
    var defaultTiming = 4000;
    var carouselTiming = $('.owl-item.active .item').attr('timing') ? $('.owl-item.active .item').attr('timing') : defaultTiming;    if(slidercode!='undefined' && slidercode!="1"){
        owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
        setTimeout(function () {
            owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel',[carouselTiming]);
        },carouselTiming);
    }else{
        clearTimeout()
        owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay'); // hear code need help
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the php tag?

Comment: thanks but this is not my answer